# How to mock object of data?

Tags: react-native, redux, jestjs

I'm using React Native with Expo, Jest for snapshot testing and Redux Toolkit with query. I want to create a snapshot but always getting an error `TypeError`. I think problem is in my mocks, I don't know how to mock an entire object of data. Example below:

```
jest.mock('../../services', () => ({
  useGetOfficeDataQuery: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('Biuro księgowe')
}));


it('renders correctly', () => {
  const snap = renderer.create(<ContactScreen />).toJSON();
  expect(snap).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

But in this mock I need to mock entire object like this below:

```
{
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "name": "Xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "nip": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "phone": null,
    "city": "xxxxx",
    "zip_code": "xx-xxx",
    "street": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "house_number": "xxxxxxx",
    "room_number": "xx",
    "email": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "email_correspondence": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: `.mockReturnValue({ "id": "xxx", ... });`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, getting `Parsing error: ',' expected`

Comment: Oh sorry, you can't have the `;` there because you're already inside an object, it _should_ be a `,`.

Comment: It's not the `;` on the end of line,  VSC underlines `"id":` but not the next part `"xxxxxx"`. It expect that I'll change the `:` to `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out, to mock an object I needed to wrap this in `{ }` and write it like a json, code example below:

```
jest.mock('../../services', () => ({
  useGetOfficeDataQuery: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    name: "xxxxxxxxxx",
  }),
}));
```